# Regex for email validation Not Allow all number for a part

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with regex for model email validation, I using this code:

`^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$` --> `(https://emailregex.com/)`

I will modify become:

```
123@123.com --> invalid(if before @ all number or after @ all number)
123a@123a.com --> valid(if before @ must combine string or only string and after @ combine string or only string)
```

Anybody improve my code, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding negative lookahead to your regex should do it:

```js
const regex = /^(?!\d+@)\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?!\d+\.)\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
[ 'a@b.com',
  'a123@b123.com',
  '123@b.com',
  'a@123.com'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
a@b.com ==> true
a123@b123.com ==> true
123@b.com ==> false
a@123.com ==> false
```

Explanation:

- first lookahead `^(?!\d+@)`: not 1+ digits from start to `@`
- second lookahead `@(?!\d+\.)`: not 1+ digits from `@` to next dot
- you could add additional lookaheads for the punctuation & word sequence after that if needed